# how to properly use hdutils to create a DMG on a (Travis) OSX VM

Tags: macos, travis-ci, hdiutil

Hello I have a script that creates a MacOSX image and then copies stuff to it.
The script was tested and worked fine until I tried to implement it in a Travis build.
This is where things get interesting. The bit of code that is of interest is as follows:

```
    hdiutil create "$dmg" -srcfolder tmp -fs HFS+ -format UDRW -volname Fiji -attach
    cp resources/install-fiji.jpg /Volumes/Fiji/.background.jpg
```

This fails because I am working in a VM and the /Volumes directory is not shared by the VM. If I try listing the directory I get:

```
    ls -la /Volumes
    ls: VMware Shared Folders: Input/output error
```

Even though the hdiutil command did not fail and in fact happily reported:

```
    /dev/disk1              GUID_partition_scheme           
    /dev/disk1s1            Apple_HFS                       /Volumes/Fiji
```

How can I get around this problem? Maybe mount on a different mount point?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've figured out that I can just mount to something else after the creation command

```
    hdiutil create "$dmg" -srcfolder tmp -fs HFS+ -format UDRW -volname Fiji
    mkdir /tmp/Fiji
    hdiutil attach "$dmg" -mountpoint /tmp/Fiji
```